# Kind of Launchy/Quicksilver to switch between Firefox tabs

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I use many tabs in Firefox, and I would like an addon to switch between tabs à la Launchy :

- press a shortcut
- type a part of the tab name I want to go
- select the tab I want

Does anybody know such an addon?

Edit: Finally I went with [Find In Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8078)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://labs.mozilla.com/ubiquity/
Ubiquity has a "Switch To Tab" function, among it's almost endless ranks.

Comment: I knew Ubiquity, but I did not know it could do it! Great! Ctrl-space -> I type the name of my tab, and it suggests me to switch to this tab!

Comment: Ubiquity is nice, but makes Firefox consume too much memory!

Answer (score 2):

If you install the [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) extension there's an option that allows that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

See [here on How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/quick-tip-firefox-ctrltab-popup-menu-switcher/)

Comment: I already have Tab Mix Plus, I did not kow this feature, but it is not really useful when I need to find a tab in many tabs, and the only thing I remember is the tab name!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `ctrl-[index of tab]` navigation.

Cons:

- it doesnt allow for the typing in of the name as stated in your spec.
- you need to know the index of the tab (ie, you need to count)
- it only works on 9 tabs

Pros:

- fewer key strokes
- it is built-in
- it seems to be standard (chrome works the same way).

Comment: I have several dozens of tabs, and my problem is that I spend some time searching where is the tab I want to reach, so, beside the fact that I have more than 9 tabs, I will have to count the tabs to press the right key...

Comment: The Cons win.

Comment: The Pros do it for me.  I have a handful of tabs that I use throughout the day (calendar, internal wiki, Stack Overflow, SuperUser, several documentation pages, etc) and a bunch of other tabs that are used less often (mostly things I've been meaning to read).  I can just arrange the ones I keeping switching to at the start, and have instant access.

Answer (score 0):

On a connected note: problem of tab switching is a more general one, since it'd be just as natural to switch windows with search too. The solution is essentially to give up the tab concept and let the OS do window switching and displaying for you. It's painlessly possible in Linux distributions, with some pain probably under Windows and Mac OSX as well. One example is [iswitchwin](http://martinman.net/software/iswitchwin/) for Linux, there is something called [PyGo-y](http://pylaunchy.sourceforge.net/docs/pygoy.html) for Launchy as well, but I remember not being able to run it.

Comment: Already using PyGo-y, it's great! Would be nice if it could search in my Firefox tabs too, but I think I'm asking too much.